# Virt-Manager won't start due to problem with libxml2 not importing in python

Tags: arch-linux, python, kvm, dependencies, virt-manager

I have been happily using KVM and virt-manger on Arch Linux for about a year now. This morning, one of my VMs broke (that is another story which I don't think is related), and I decided that it would just be easiest to delete it and virt-install again.

However, after deleting this VM via the virt-manager interface, I was no longer able to start virt-manager:

```
$ virt-install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virt-install", line 15, in <module>
    import virtinst
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from virtinst.domain import *  # pylint: disable=wildcard-import
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/domain/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .blkiotune import DomainBlkiotune
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/domain/blkiotune.py", line 8, in <module>
    from ..xmlbuilder import XMLBuilder, XMLChildProperty, XMLProperty
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/xmlbuilder.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .xmlapi import XMLAPI
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/xmlapi.py", line 7, in <module>
    import libxml2
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 779, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 911, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 580, in _compile_bytecode
EOFError: marshal data too short
```

It seems that libxml2 is broken in some way:

```
Python 3.8.3 (default, May 17 2020, 18:15:42) 
[GCC 10.1.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import libxml2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 779, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 911, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 580, in _compile_bytecode
EOFError: marshal data too short
```

I have tried updating my system as well as removing and reinstalling the obvious packages, `libvirt`, `virt-manager`, `libxml2` and `libvirt-python`, and that has not helped, nor has the somewhat dangerous `pacman -Syyu`.

Any ideas about what might be broken here?

I am using the LTS kernel, 5.4. Python version is 3.8. Virt-manager is 2.2.1

Also, if I just start python, I can load all the modules mentioned in the above error without any issue.

I'm close to just doing a clean reinstall, but that is a terrible bother, and I'd like to avoid it if I can just fix some dependencies in Arch

edit:
As suggested in the comment, I tried running strace and here is the output (perhaps if I look at it long enough I will have some insight about which file might be corrupted). File corruption does seem likely as I ran out of disk space on root.

```
~]$ strace python -c 'import libxml2'
#output was too big to paste in here, so I cut out everything but the last part, which is what seemed most likely to be relevant
###..........many lines deleted....####
###..........many lines deleted....####
###..........many lines deleted....####
getcwd("/home/boss", 1024)              = 11
stat("/home/boss", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0750, st_size=3488, ...}) = 0
stat("/home/boss", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0750, st_size=3488, ...}) = 0
stat("/home/boss", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0750, st_size=3488, ...}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/boss", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0750, st_size=3488, ...}) = 0
getdents64(3, /* 41 entries */, 32768)  = 1416
getdents64(3, /* 0 entries */, 32768)   = 0
close(3)                                = 0
stat("/usr/lib/python3.8", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=8192, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=8192, ...}) = 0
stat("/home/boss/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0700, st_size=3488, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=8192, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/libxml2.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=345896, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/libxml2.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=345896, ...}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/__pycache__/libxml2.cpython-38.pyc", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=139264, ...}) = 0
ioctl(3, TCGETS, 0x7fffbe383200)        = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = 0
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = 0
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=139264, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 143360, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f2172e15000
read(3, "U\r\r\n\0\0\0\0\203\224\246^(G\5\0\343\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 139265) = 139264
read(3, "", 1)                          = 0
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 262144, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f2172dd5000
write(2, "Traceback (most recent call last"..., 35Traceback (most recent call last):
) = 35
write(2, "  File \"<string>\", line 1, in <m"..., 39  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
) = 39
openat(AT_FDCWD, "<string>", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "<string>", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/python38.zip/<string>", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/python3.8/<string>", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/<string>", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/boss/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/<string>", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/<string>", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2, "  File \"<frozen importlib._boots"..., 68  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
) = 68
openat(AT_FDCWD, "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/python38.zip/<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/python3.8/<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/boss/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2, "  File \"<frozen importlib._boots"..., 77  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
) = 77
openat(AT_FDCWD, "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/python38.zip/<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/python3.8/<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/boss/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2, "  File \"<frozen importlib._boots"..., 68  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
) = 68
openat(AT_FDCWD, "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/python38.zip/<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/python3.8/<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/boss/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2, "  File \"<frozen importlib._boots"..., 74  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 779, in exec_module
) = 74
openat(AT_FDCWD, "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/python38.zip/<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/python3.8/<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/boss/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2, "  File \"<frozen importlib._boots"..., 71  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 911, in get_code
) = 71
openat(AT_FDCWD, "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/python38.zip/<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/python3.8/<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/boss/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2, "  File \"<frozen importlib._boots"..., 80  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 580, in _compile_bytecode
) = 80
openat(AT_FDCWD, "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/python38.zip/<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/python3.8/<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/boss/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2, "EOFError: marshal data too short"..., 33EOFError: marshal data too short
) = 33
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f21734763e0}, {sa_handler=0x7f21736ca3a2, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f21734763e0}, 8) = 0
munmap(0x7f2172dd5000, 262144)          = 0
munmap(0x7f2172e15000, 143360)          = 0
sigaltstack(NULL, {ss_sp=0x5610230bc580, ss_flags=0, ss_size=16384}) = 0
sigaltstack({ss_sp=NULL, ss_flags=SS_DISABLE, ss_size=0}, NULL) = 0
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

edit:
[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53855836/keyerror-frozen-importlib-bootstrap-error-on-second-library-import-in-spyder) seems promising, but I have no idea where I would check to see if `__init__.py` is missing.

Comment: Try `strace` on the python process where you `import libxml2` to see what file it opens prior to marshal error. Might be a corrupt .pyc file.

Comment: OK I tried that and will add it to the question (although I feel pretty clueless about interpreting it).

Comment: Remove `/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/__pycache__/libxml2.cpython-38.pyc`, try importing again. If import succeeds, remove python-libxlml2 and reinstall.

Comment: Yes, that worked! Put it as an answer and I'll mark it. (btw on Arch the package is just called libxml2, not python-libxml2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely the reason is a corrupt `.pyc` file.

Try `strace` on the python process where you `import libxml2` to see what file it opens prior to marshal error.

Then, remove that file (python does not require `.pyc` files to be present to work) and `import libxml2` again. If the import succeeds, remove `python-libxml2` and reinstall it (which should regenerate the faulty `.pyc` file).

Comment: Yes, that did it, thank you! Unfortunately I don't think that was all that got corrupted, as I started getting weird crashes after getting my VMs up and running.

Comment: You could try force-reinstalling all installed packages.

Comment: Too late. Arch was too high-maintenance anyway.